# PXE boot in uefi mode

Tags: uefi, pxe

I'm building a pxeboot server and including both legacy boot and uefi boot options. The legacy boot works perfectly but while doing an installation in uefi mode, the client machine network boots, completes the installation and then reboots and starts network booting again. In my elilo.conf file, my default option is to boot from local hard disk but I'm not sure if the syntax is correct:

```
#-----elilo.conf-----
default=local
timeout=300
chooser=simple
message=my_msg

image=LOCALBOOT
  label=local

#....(other images)
```

Why doesn't the client machine boot from hard disk after a successful installation?

Answer (score 1):

If your booting UEFI PC is set for net-booting then surely your PXE server is mistakenly providing a BIOS NBP i.e. pxelinux.0. When the PC tries to run the received BIOS NBP it fails (because it is not an EFI NBP) then it reboots.

EDI:

if you finished the installation and then you see after re-boot that the PC boots again from the net then you have to alter the boot priority from your UEFI console. Make the boot from HDD appear before than the boot from network (PXE)

Comment: No it completes an installation and then reboots, and then starts network booting again..

Comment: see the edit of the answer

Comment: Yeah, that's one way to do it, but its manual. Since this is a PXE installation, I wanted everything to be automatic. When I do a legacy BIOS install, the client installs, reboots and then upon timeout it defaults to booting from the hard disk so that works perfectly for me. I was wondering if I could do the same in UEFI mode?

Comment: when you do a legacy install the BIOS has a boot order like HDD,PXE then when the disk is empty the PC boots PXE but as soon there's a bootable OS in the HDD the PC boots from HDD. When Booting in EFI mode you must set a similar boot order if it is not the default.